# What is the proper way to declare a javascript standalone library that works in nodejs, browser, commonJS, and AMD?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-browser

so in my library file I declare something like this:

```
(function(mylib){

"use strict";

 mylib.funcA = function () {return "A"};
 mylib.funcB = function () {return "B"};

})(typeof mylib == "undefined" ? (this["mylib"]={}) : mylib);
```

//I've been using something like this and it works in the browser I can use

```
 <script src="mylib.js"></script>
 <script>
      console.log(mylib.funcA()); // outputs "A"
      console.log(mylib.funcB()); // outputs "B"
 </script>
```

// and in nodejs I can use

```
 mylib = require("mylib.js")["mylib"];
 console.log(mylib.funcA()); // outputs "A"
 console.log(mylib.funcB()); // outputs "B"
```

But I want to just have a wrapper method that I can user that declares the library correctly and works in all the common flavors of js.

I've seen several different answers on stack-overflow but no one with just a simple example of the blessed way to do this.  Help appreciated!

Comment: You want to write some kind of a wrapper in order to remove the "<script src="mylib.js"></script>" and "mylib = require("mylib.js")["mylib"];" lines?

Comment: @JeroenHeier To clarify, I want a common way to declare such a module.

So in the browser the 
     <script src="mylib.js"></script> 

and in node 
     mylib = require("mylib.js")["mylib"];

are still fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want an UMD module.

The UMD standard repository has one that fits your needs: https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/returnExports.js

Nore info and more templates here: https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Comment: Very helpful!  Is there a chart of supported environments (e.g. which browsers or node versions ) of where this declaration should work?

Comment: I tried this and I'm not sure I'm using this correctly can you point to a github lib that uses this as an example?  Does this require using a build tool or should I just wrap code in the bottom function() body?

Comment: All the big libraries I know are using approach like this so they support at least AMD, commons and bare script usage.